# @StreamListener to inbound a list of messages

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm currently using `@StreamListener` to inbound messages one-by-one and then process it in our service class to save it in db.

Instead, I want to inbound a list of messages (say 100) at a time and then process it to save all these 100 messages at once to avoid repetitive calls to DB.

How can we achieve this using `@StreamListener`.